# How would I activate an ATtiny85 microcontroller using a transistor?

Tags: arduino, transistors, circuit-design, attiny, attiny85

I am using a TIP120 transistor and an ATtiny85. The RF signal goes into the base. I want to then activate the ATtiny85 to run code. However, my circuit starts running code without an RF signal going into the base.

Here is my schematic. As stated in my comments please disregard the values associated in the circuit for now. I need help with polarity and circuit structure. The buck converters are stepping down the 12 volts down to 5 volts for the RF receiver and the ATtiny85.

[image: schematic]

Comment: To use a transistor as a DC switch enabled with an RF input you would need to first convert the RF signal into a DC signal by using for example one or more diodes and a few capacitors. Show us the circuit you have designed so far.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this for me. [ Schematic has been added into the question ] Please ignore the values in the circuit for now as I had to pick out stuff that I used in my real circuit that my software didn't have available at the time. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: What are A1 and A2?